# Passing array from php to javascript stops my program

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I'm an absolute beginner with a clock ticking towards a deadline: please excuse if this is a simple question, but I have spent six hours unsuccessfully searching for a solution:

My PHP code imports 2603 values (text and integer) from MYSQL and places them in an array. I then implode the array. Finally, I try to import it into javascript. At this point, my code stops running.

The relevant PHP code (after succesful db connection:

```
$previousdecisions=array();
$carryover=array();
$countera=1;        
$query="SELECT * FROM strategicdecisions".$teamname;
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $carryover[] = $countera;
    $carryover[]=$row['decisionname'];
    $carryover[]=$row['round1'];
    $carryover[]=$row['round2'];
    $carryover[]=$row['round3'];
    $carryover[]=$row['round4'];
    $carryover[]=$row['round5'];
    $carryover[]=$row['round6'];
    $carryover[]=$row['round7'];
    $carryover[]=$row['round8'];
    $carryover[]=$row['round9'];
    $carryover[]=$row['round10'];
    $countera++;        
}
```

"decisionname" values are text, all other values are integers.

If I then print_r(array_values($carryover)); it is an array in exactly the manner I want (with 2603 values). Then I implode the array:

```
 $carryover = implode(",", $carryover);
```

In javascript, I try to import the array as follows:

```
var previousdecisions = "<?php echo $carryover; ?>".split(","); 
for(a=0; a < previousdecisions.length; a++) {
    document.write("<li>"+previousdecisions[a]+"</li>");
}
```

This 'stops' my program (i.e. I don't receive an error message, but none of the following code is carried out anymore.

I have tried the same thing with json_encode (which I would prefer to avoid) and the exact same thing happens.

I would be extremely grateful for any help.

Comment: You should normalise your database; "round1 - round10" should be in a separate table.

Comment: Tried passing the values via JSON?

Comment: Are there any errors on your JavaScript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an obviouse mistake so it is very hard to get the error.

I would try several things:

- Don't write over an array a string. If the program is getting bigger it is very confusing if you start with an array and on the bottom it is a string. Use different names!
- Maybe the variable is not globally declared. So try

  ```
  var previousdecisions = "<?php var_dump($carryover); echo $carryover; ?>";
  ```

  before you echo. You will see via var_dump() if the variable is declared and what is written into.
- If you see that the variable is declared you shouldn't split before you don't know if it is a string. So try to leave out the split and look into the variable via

  ```
  console.log(previousdecisions);
  ```

If none of this work for you then comment your new explorations and I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

In php do:

```
$json = json_encode($carryover);
```

the in the HTML do:

```
<script>
var previousdecisions = JSON.pasrse("<?php echo $json; ?>"); 
</script>
```

This is much easier using JSON